# Automating Tableau Graphs through Python

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have a program that returns its results in a CSV file. I want to plot this data on Tableau each time and get a graph as output. How can I do this? Can Tableau API help here? (Python way preferred).

Comment: Hi Akshay, welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm sorry to say that right now you're not likely to get answers on this question since it doesn't present a specific problem that you're having. Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask) and see if you can update your question. Right now this is likely to actually be closed as opinion-based since it looks like you're asking for an opinion about what's the best way to do it.

Comment: Post some example code you've tried and threw a traceback at you. If that's implemented inside your question we can help you much better.